# In rust, how do I define a global variable/constant whose value is the result of a function?

Tags: rust, global-variables

I have a function without argument that builds and returns a `Vec`, and the corresponding result is always the same. I want to call that function only once and store its result in a global variable or constant that all functions in my program will be able to access. How do I do that ? My first try was to try to define a `const` or a `static`, but this is not allowed:

```
error[E0015]: calls in statics are limited to struct and enum constructors
 --> src/main.rs:2:30
  |
2 | static ALL: Vec<Knowledge> = Knowledge::all();
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: a limited form of compile-time function evaluation is available on a nightly compiler via `const fn`
 --> src/main.rs:2:30
  |
2 | static ALL: Vec<Knowledge> = Knowledge::all();
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Using `let` outside a function won't work either. How should I do? Yes, the error message says I could use nightly, but I don't want to do that and prefer staying with the canonic version of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on your case.
If you rely on stable compiler your best chance is the [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) crate.

If you are willing to do some experiments with the nightly compiler, you can try the [const fn](https://github.com/nox/rust-rfcs/blob/master/text/0911-const-fn.md) [feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24111).
But be aware, that there are certain limitations on what const fn can do.